# Custom Outlook Calendar Recurrence

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I need to setup an appointment on my Outlook 2010 calendar that recurs the Wednesday following the last Sunday of the month. I have not figured out a way to do this with Outlook. Anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I suppose is to set two different recurring appointments one for the last Wednesday and the other for the first Wednesday of a month. Once you set it up, you will require to go to your calendar and manually select and delete the occurence for the entry that does not meet your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that's not possible using the Outlook recurrence dialog.  It could be done by writing a program that controls Outlook, but that hardly seems worth the effort.  Wouldn't copy and paste be easier for just one appointment each month?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a reminder, you could set the appointment for the first Sunday of each month and set a reminder for four days before that.

If you want the time to show as busy on your calendar, I am not sure how to do anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I used for a similar issue. See if [this](https://superuser.com/a/371050/97028) workaround will work. Hope it helps.